# htaccess without using all parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website with categories and I should pagination on those categories.

the first page of the category is:

```
http://www.domain.com/cat/category-name/
```

the others pages (with the pagination) should be like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/cat/category-name/2/
```

-> the number (2 for example) is the page number.

this is what I wrote on htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^cat/(.*)/(.*)/$ cat.php?name=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

**Thr problem** is that if I write like this, I have to write a number.. and the main page of the category shouldn't be with number. what can I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(quite a naive solution)*

You could use two RewriteRules :

- The one you already have -- it'll match when there is a page number
- And one without that page number

Comment: WORKING. I thought about it too but I put the "one without that page number" before and not after.. my mistake. I think it's ok.. thank you.